# Integer input without submit buttom to instantly set a loop limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am trying to set the first input "Enter # of Circles" as a variable "ContestantNum" **without a submit button** which is then supposed to be the limit in the loop (i=0; **i<=ContestantNum;** i++)

Not sure if there is any event to be applied in addEventListener() that can pull the data from the input with no submit.

Thanks Alot!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
  <head>

    <title>Intro Webpage!</title>

     <style>
     div {
     width: 120px;
     height: 120px;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: 1px;
         }
     </style>

     <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0; target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <br>
       <b>Enter # of Circles<b>
       <br>
    <input type="integer" id="circles">   
           </b></b>
    <form>
    <div id="Participentfieldwrap">
      <svg height="100" width="200">
    <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100000000" y2="10000" style="stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5" />

       <svg height="100" width="100">
              <circle id="cir" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" /> 
       </svg>
       </svg>
       <br>
       <b>Color<b>
       <br>
    <input type="integer" id="Color">
           </b></b>
```

//Inputing integer 1, 2 or 3 which instantly applies color formatting (RGB) to circle in the same div

```
            var cir = document.getElementById("cir");
            var into = document.getElementById("Color");
           into.addEventListener("keyup",myFunction,false);

            function myFunction() {
                if (document.getElementById("Color").value == 1) 
                    cir.style.fill = "green";
                else if (document.getElementById("Color").value == 2) 
                    cir.style.fill = "red";
                else if (document.getElementById("Color").value == 3) 
                    cir.style.fill = "blue";
                else cir.style.fill = "Yellow";
                                  }

       </script>
    </div>        
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
```

//Loop for creating multiple divs in a form using a limit that is set in an integer input

```
    var participantsField = document.getElementById("Participentfieldwrap"),
        form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0],
        ContestantNum = document.getElementById("circles"),
        i;

    for(i=0; i<=ContestantNum; i++){
      var clone = participantsField.cloneNode(true);
      form.appendChild(clone);
    }
  </script>

    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Poll the data through a timer, like twice a second

Answer (score 0):

When do you need the loop to start, on page load or when the input has changed? You could tie the onkey up event to your input, which gives you access to the input value in the event handler, which could then set the ContestantNum var.

Comment: yes, when the input has changed. 
That is the exact method i have tried yet for some reason it is not working.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

//Loop for creating multiple divs in a form using a limit that is set in an integer input



document.getElementById("circles").addEventListener("onkeyup", youFunction);

function youFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("circles").value;
   }


        var participantsField = document.getElementById("Participentfieldwrap"),
            form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];

        var i;

for(i=0; i<=x; i++){
var clone = participantsField.cloneNode(true);
 form.appendChild(clone);
        } </script>

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an event such as `keydown, keypress` etc, with a debounce:

```js
var participantsField = document.getElementById("Participentfieldwrap"),
  form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0],
  ContestantNum = document.getElementById("circles"),
  i, timer;

function createCircles(val) {
  for (i = 0; i <= val; i++) {
    var clone = participantsField.cloneNode(true);
    form.appendChild(clone);
  }
}

ContestantNum.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
   if(timer){ clearTimeout(timer); }

   timer = setTimeout(function(){
     createCircles(ContestantNum.value);
   }, 800);
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot! it is very close but it is incrementing everytime a value enters the input field

Comment: You could try increasing the timeout delay to `800,900 ms`.